# Create Unicode from a hex number in C++

Tags: unicode, hex

My objective is to take a character which represents to UK pound symbol and convert it to it's unicode equivalent in a string.

Here's my code and output so far from my test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char x = 163;
    unsigned char ux = x;
    const char *str  = "\u00A3";

    printf("x: %d\n", x);
    printf("ux: %d %x\n", ux, ux);
    printf("str: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
$ ./pound 
x: -93
ux: 163 a3
str: £
```

My goal is to take the unsigned char 0xA3 and put it into a string representing the unicode UK pound representation: "\u00A3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is your question? Anyway, you say you're writing C++, but you're using char* and printf and stdlib.h so you're really writing C, and base C does not support unicode. Remember that a char in C is not a "character" it's just a byte, and a char* is not an array of characters, it's an array of bytes. When you printf the "\u00A3" string in your sample program, you are not printing a unicode character, you are actually printing those literal bytes, and your terminal is helping you out and interpreting them as a unicode character. The fact that it correctly prints the £ character is just coincidence. You can see this for yourself. If you printf str[0] in your sample program you should just see the "\" character.

If you want to use unicode correctly in C you'll need to use a library. There are many to choose from and I haven't used any of them enough to recommend one. Or you'll need to use C++11 or newer and use std::wstring and friends. But what you are doing is not real unicode and will not work as you expect in the long run.